# Panframe Sdk: forword video using "playWithSeekTo:onKeyFrame:" Method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here i am sending code for player view of panframe sdk

```
 CMTime t = [pfAsset getPlaybackTime];
 CMTime seekingCM = CMTimeMake(t.value+10000000, t.timescale);
 [pfView run];
 //[pfAsset stop];
 [pfAsset playWithSeekTo:seekingCM onKeyFrame:YES];

 slider.value = CMTimeGetSeconds(t);
 [pfAsset play];return;
```

Please advise how it will work.